# ActionListener and ActionEvent best practise query

Tags: java, actionlistener, actionevent

within my code I currently have all my ActionListener's as Anonymous inner classes like so:

```
item.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            //code here
        }
    }
```

now this feels fine for me when the code is no more than 20ish lines however it feels clunky for more than 20 lines.
So, I could implement ActionListener and have a method

```
ActionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
{
    if ae.getSource() == item
    {
        // code here too
    }
}
```

but I have no intention of re-using this code anywhere else...
I could create another class to handle this as well but that doesnt really help as I still wish to use variables that were instantiated within my parent class.

What I would really like to do is to use some syntax like this:

```
private void btnAction()
{
    // do code
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    btn.addActionListener(btnAction)
}
```

I feel that this would look best as I can hide the events at the bottom and focus on the bulk of the running project.
Is this possible to achieve?

Comment: Why not use a non-anonymous inner class?

Comment: Could you please explain this? I am not familiar with a non-anonymous inner class

Comment: A basic [inner class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html), with a name, defined as a member of the class.

Answer (score 0):

Using Java 8, you can do that:

```
btn.addActionListener(e -> btnAction());
```

Read more about lambdas starting here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/architect-lambdas-part1-2080972.html

Comment: Unfortunately... I am using Java 6. lambdas are indeed far easier and less cluttered but unfortunately I do not have the correct Java version to utilize them :(

Comment: @penfold1992 Java 6 reached its end of life in February of 2013. Using it is a pretty big security risk, so you better have a very good reason for using it!

Comment: well i have a good enough reason... I work for a very large company of over 50,000 people and I do not have any power to convince the company that it would be necessary to update to Java 8.
its just what I have to work with :(

Answer (score 0):

If all the buttons run the same code, you can define a (named) inner class that implements ActionListener and runs the code, or you can even make your enclosing class an `ActionListener` and add it as the action listener for all the buttons, so that its `actionPerformed()` runs the code for all.

---

If, on the other hand, each button requires a different action, you can have the different actions as methods like you requestod. I'd suggest passing the event to them in case you need event information:

```
private void btnActionOK(ActionEvent e) {
    // do code
}
private void btnActionBack(ActionEvent e) {
    // do code
}
private void btnActionForward(ActionEvent e) {
    // do code
}
```

etc.

Then you create the anonymous class, but the only thing its `actionPerformed()` does is call the appropriate method.

```
okButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        btnActionOK(e);
    }
});
backButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        btnActionBack(e);
    }
});
forwardButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        btnActionForward(e);
    }
});
```

An inner class can call a method of the enclosing class. This way, you keep the anonymous classes short, and you can put all the long code in its own methods in the enclosing class.